# PHP: single and double quotes issue in echo-ed string?

Tags: php

I have a very simple issue which I don't know how to fix.

Basically, I have this string:

```
$variable = '<input type="button" value="something" onclick="location.href = 'my-page.php';" />';
```

the issue is the `onclick="..."` on the button.

when i run my code, it kills the entire page without any errors.

Could someone please let me know if there is a way to sort this out?

Comment: Escape the `'` using `\'` instead.
$variable = '<input type="button" value="something" onclick="location.href = \'my-page.php\';" />';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the apostrophes:

```
$variable = '<input ... onclick="location.href = \'my-page.php\';" />';
```